# Facebook oauth 2.5 expired today = 400 Bad request in prod

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, oauth, facebook-unity-sdk

Today (April 12th 2018) FB deprecated oauth 2.5 and all of my Unity android game's users got error: "400 Bad Request".
I've added the all possible redirect URI's in developer settings and upgraded the oauth to 2.6 (and also tried 2.7) but it is still not working.
Production users receive same "400 Bad request" error and my game login is not working.
Please give me some ideas on how to fix this without creating new app update that will take months to update to all users.

This is the prod code that fails:

```
FB.API("/me?fields=id,name,gender,first_name,last_name,email", HttpMethod.GET, new FacebookDelegate<IGraphResult>((IGraphResult e) => onFBUserInfo(e)));
```

Thank you!!!

**UPDATE**: The exception is: OAuthException 2500 
An active access token must be used to query information about the current

Comment: That part of the code only fails, because you don’t have an active access token. So what you actually need to debug, is why your login fails.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, but the FB.LogInWithReadPermissions succeeds. I get empty "Error" string and RawResult that looks valid. It has the token. I wonder if my old Unity FB sdk is able to parse it properly. The thing is..I have to fix it without updating the Unity SDK. It is v. 7.5.0

Comment: @Cbroe I noticed that the rawResult has key_hash value ending with \n  Can it be the problem?

Comment: The only thing I can think of that would be relevant in that regard is the change of format the token is returned in, used to be form/url-encoded, and is now JSON. But that change happened with API v2.3 already, so if that was it you should have noticed this earlier ... https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/archive#v2_3_changes

Comment: I tried updating to latest FB SDK 7.11 but it returns the same error. The problem should be in developer page configuration. I thought it is the redirect uri's but they aren't used when authenticating with the FB app (through the SDK) right?

Comment: @CBroe if I revoke the FB app permissions, then it works..but I can't ask all my users to revoke the app from their FB accounts. Is it possible to do it from app admin?

Comment: Well you can remove permissions/revoke login completely using an API call - but since you don't have a user token, you would need to use the app access token, and that is something you don't want to expose in client-side code. If you had a list of the app-scoped user ids stored somewhere (nope, no API for that, before you ask) then you could do it from a server ... but otherwise, I don't think there's a scenario where you could make use of that in a responsible way.

Comment: @CBroe I have list of all user scoped id's in my database. How can I do the removal in server side? Thanks

Comment: Basically a DELETE request to `/{user-id}/permissions`, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking#revoking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @CBroe I managed to solve the problem by deleting user permission using his scoped_id and getting App Token. Here is the Graph Explorer screenshot.
Now I'll automate the process and revoke all users:
[image]

**UPDATE**: I was able to make graph api DELETE script, which resets my users permissions and  they are able to login normally.
However, the root cause of the issue seems to be on facebook's side as this is what FB tech support replied:

> The issue seems to be on our side. We have just applied a fix to
>   address FB Login issues with Unity, related to access token

Here is my JS reset permission script:

```
function deleteALL(index, endIndex) {
    var access_token = "<INSERT YOUR APP TOKEN HERE>";
    var URL = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/"+arr[index]+"/permissions/?method=delete&access_token="+access_token;
    $.ajax({
      url: URL,
      context: document.body
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log("SUCCESS:"+data.success+" index: "+index);
      if (endIndex > index+1)
          deleteALL(index+1, endIndex);
    }).fail(function() {
        console.log("FAILED: index: "+index);
      if (arr.length > index+1)
          deleteALL(index+1, endIndex);
    });
}
```